# MongoDB find key on nested object KEY (JSON)

Tags: json, mongodb, nested

So pretty new and absolutely uneducated on MongoDB.

Having this JSON structure:

```
{
"id": "123456",
"makes": {
    "abc": {
        "att1": 4,
        "att2": "fffff",
        "att3": 46
        },
    "fgh": {
        "att1": 8,
        "att2": "ggggg",
        "att3": 6
    },
    "rty": {
        "att1": 3,
        "att2": "hhhh",
        "att3": 4
        },
    "iop": {
        "att1": 4,
        "att2": "llll",
        "att3": 3
        }
}
```

}

how can I query the DB for "fgh" make?
I tried:

```
db.<myCollection>.find({"makes":"fgh"})
```

but that doesn't work.
It works fine if I write:

```
db.<myCollection>.find({"makes.fgh.att1":8})
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you try to query for makes.fgh, you don't do a query on the content, but on the structure, as "fgh" is not a value but a sub-document.

You can achieve this with a $exists search:

```
db.myCollection.find( { "makes.fgh" : { $exists : true } })
```

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/ for reference.

To integrate @chridam's helpful comment:

If you are only interested in *that* sub-document, you can also add a projection to the find:

```
db.myCollection.find({ "makes.fgh" : { $exists : true }}, { "makes.fgh" : 1 })
```

Have a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find for details.

Comment: Also worth mentioning the projection of the subdocument after the query `db.<myCollection>.find({ "makes.fgh": { "$exists": true } }, { "makes.fgh": 1 })`

Comment: Yes, right. Edited the answer to include this fact.

Comment: It's starting to make more sense now, thanks both for your help!

Comment: A gotcha for the [node driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native) - projection param should have "projection" as a key, e.g. `db.<myCollection>.find({ "makes.fgh": { "$exists": true } }, { projection: { "makes.fgh": 1 }})`

Comment: Would it be possible to somehow pattern match?  eg: fg*?

Comment: @openCivilisation No, I am not aware of such a feature.